# ComboBox did not work after setting project to Unicode

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, resource-files

I changed my project properties to Unicode and compiling works great but my ComboBox didn't work.

Here some code:

```
COMBOBOX    IDC_DEBUGLEVEL, 478, 20, 49, 14, CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SIMPLE  | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

To add some items into this ComboBox I do:

```
cPipe = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_DEBUGLEVEL);
cPipe->AddString(L"label");
```

If I want to open the dropdownlist I didnt't get it. Only a small line with the correct width but the height seems to be zero. It looks like

[image: Empty ComboBox]

I have only this black line but my items are added. I can choose the items with my keyboard.

Comment: You need to set the height of the combobox larger in the resource. Change 14 to something bigger (e.g. 200).

Comment: Or, do it in the resource editor by clicking the down arrow on the combo box, and then resizing it.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060310-17/?p=31973/

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thx., that was my mistake

Comment: You are using 2 different symbolic constants for the control ID's (`IDC_DEBUGLEVEL` and `IDC_FILTER_PIPE`). Is this intentional? Do they have the same value? If so, why are there 2 symbols defined? If not, you should really post real code.

Comment: @IInspectable Changed it ... My mistake but it didn't changed anything

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Please transform your comment into an answer.